# entityManager.createNativeQuery does not return a typed result

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I need select **native query**  with **entityManager**. I found method:

```
public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass);
```

And try use it:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(readyQuery, SmevMessage.class);
return query.getResultList();
```

But IDE still highlights as a warning:

[image]

Why then does this method exist? and what should i do to fix it?

Comment: It is a warning NOT an error. You cannot fix it as the API is inconsistent here. The `Query` isn't . If you look at the `createQuery` method (for JPQL) it returns `TypedQuery` where this one isn't. You could hide the warning by using an `@SuppressWarning` annotation but that is all you can do.

Comment: Yes, when I use `TypedQuery q = em.createQuery()` there is no warning. But then the methods differ `public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString);` and `public Query createNativeQuery(String sqlString, Class resultClass);`? - `resultClass` as if hinting that i should get type

Comment: As stated `createQuery` is for JPQL... I mentioned it to highlight the inconsistency in the API of the `EntityManager`.

Comment: Your persistence provider instantiates managed entity objects of the provided `resultClass` and returns them if you call the `getSingleResult` or `getResultList`methods. 
But as explained in my answer below, the method only returns an untyped `Query`. That's why your IDE shows a warning, which you can ignore.

Answer (score 4):

Which warning do you get? Does your IDE only warn you about the unchecked conversion of the returned `List`?

You can ignore that one. Unfortunately, the `createNativeQuery` method returns an untyped `Query`. There is no way you can fix that warning. If it really bothers you, you can suppress it with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

And please be aware that you need to provide an entity class as the value of the `resultClass` parameter, as I explained [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/). So, in your case, `SmevMessage` has to be an entity. If you want to map your query result to a DTO, you need to [define an `@SqlResultSetMapping`](https://thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-complex-mappings/).

Comment: Now it is clear. the second parameter is needed for JPA to understand in which entity map. But it is not clear why there is still no possibility to make a typed result. I do not want to suppress warnings. I can leave as well. let it be highlighted. I was just wondering why it has not been decided yet.